# Getting basis of solution space without Gaussian elimination

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

From S.L Linear Algebra:

> Find the dimension of the space of solutions of the following systems
>   of equations. Also find a basis for this space of solutions.
>
> (a) $4x + 7y - \pi z = 0$, $2x - y +z = 0$.

We see that matrix associated with homogeneous equations (a) is:

$$A = \begin{pmatrix}
4 & 7 & - \pi  \\ 
2 & -1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$

It's therefore obvious that rank of the matrix is at most $2$. To get the precise result I simply ensure that there is a linear independence between first two rows:

$$a(4, 7, -\pi) + b(2, -1, 1) = (0, 0, 0)$$

Thus $4a + 2b =0$, $7a - b = 0$ and $-\pi a + b=0$. Considering that $a = -\frac{b}{2}$, $7(-\frac{b}{2}) - b = -\frac{7b-2b}{2}=- \frac{9b}{2}=b=0$.

Therefore it can be concluded that rank of the matrix is $2$. Then I consider the Rank-Nullity theorem:

$$\textrm{dim} \, \, \mathbb{R}^3 = \textrm{dim} \, \, \textrm{Im}(A) + \textrm{dim} \, \, \textrm{Ker}(A)$$

$$3 = 2 + \textrm{dim} \, \, \textrm{Ker}(A)$$

$$\textrm{dim} \, \, \textrm{Ker}(F)= 1$$

Thus the dimension of the space of solutions for the system of equations (a) is precisely $1$.

---

We know that dimension of the space of solutions is a $1$-dimensional space orthogonal to $A$. In order to find basis for solution space, we can extend $K=(4, 7, -\pi)$ and $B = (2, -1, 1)$ to basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Which can be done by selecting a vector $C$ such that $K, B, C$ is linearly independent, in this case, let $C=(0, 0, 1)$.

Final step is to ensure orthogonality between $K B ,C $. Using Gram-Schmidt:

$B' = (4, 7, -\pi) - \frac{\langle (2, -1, 1), \langle (4, 7, -\pi) \rangle}{\langle (2, -1, 1), \langle (2, -1, 1) \rangle} (2, -1, 1)=...$

$C' = B' - \frac{B', \langle (0, 0, 1) \rangle}{\langle (0, 0, 1), \langle (0, 0, 1) \rangle} (0, 0, 1)$=...

Therefore $S = \{C'\}$ is a basis of $\textrm{Ker}(A)$.

Is this a correct way to find basis without using Gaussian elimination method? I believe there might be few mistakes, especially during the orthogonalization step. Maybe $K, B$ should be treated as a whole matrix $A$? or maybe matrix $A$ must be flattened to a vector in $\mathbb{R}^{2 \times 3}$?

Thank you!

Comment: Your approach looks fine. As another hint: if you have two vectors in $R^3$ and look for a third one orthogonal to it, you might consider the cross product.

Comment: @Florian Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for: more elegant way to ensure orthogonality between vectors. If I may ask, how exactly can cross product be utilized in this case? Should I substitute scalar product with cross product in projection formula of Gram-Schmidt? Or should I substitute it with [triple product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product)?

Comment: Since you showed that your two row vectors are linearly independent, all you need is one vector orthogonal to both that will provide you the basis for your kernel. Hence the basis is already equal to the cross product of the two rows ($C = K \times B$). No need for Gram Schmidt. That said, if you find Gram Schmidt simpler, keep it that way. It's anyways the more generic solution (cross products only work in $R^3$).

Comment: Are the equations assumed to have domains $\Bbb{R}^3$ with coordinates $(x,y,z)$? As it stands, the equations just as well define a subspace of $\Bbb{R}^n$ for any $n\geq3$.

Comment: @Servaes I apologize, I'm not completely sure if I understand your comment. But I just constructed a coefficient matrix $A: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ from the system of equations defined above. Although it is interesting, that in all such equations in the exercise, they contain at most $3$ variables. Does this suggest something?

Comment: @Florian Oh, my bad. I forgot that cross product between $K$ and $B$ will result in $C$ that is orthogonal to both $K$ and $B$. Thank you!